# Sync objects to S3 with expires and cache-control headers using the CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to sync some objects to S3 and set the `Expires` and `Cache-Control` headers, but I'm at my wit's end here. Nothing seems to work. Here's my latest attempt:

```
aws s3 sync . s3://my-bucket \
    --expires "2020-06-16T13:27:40Z" \
    --cache-control "max-age=315360000, public, s-maxage=31536000, max-age=31536000, immutable" \
    --exclude "*" \
    --metadata-directive REPLACE \
    --include "bundles"
```

The result: no `Expires` header, no `Cache-Control` header. I've looked around in the console (only one metadata, `Content-Type`), I've used `get-object` to look at it, and I looked at the response with `curl`. I'm not really sure about `metadata-directive` - it is not mentioned under `--expires` in the docs, but the docs for the directive option indicates it *must* be set for the other ones to work. What crazy incantation must I conjure to have these headers set on my objects?

Answer (score 0):

This eventually turned out to be a PEBCAC. This does indeed work when run in isolation. I ran it as part of a multi-step process that would first sync some files, except the ones I wanted the headers on, and then sync the files with headers. Problem was, I fat-fingered the `exclude` pattern in the first sync, so basically all the files where already synced, and so the header-setting sync did nothing. Ah, ain't being a developer lovely?